# Trying to parse CSV into array for use with table and leaflet choropleth

Tags: javascript, mysql, csv, leaflet, papaparse

I am using papa.parse to extract values from a csv file into an array inside the DOM that I can then access for a table and display on parts of a leaflet.js map. There a few walls I've run into, but the first wall is the data. I'm not getting any errors with the parser as shown below, but it returns an empty array??

I'm pretty green with JS and papa had solid docs so it seemed like the best bet. I had test the php database method, but that makes it even harder for me to use the data with leaflet. If one recommends a method of "sql data to array" over converting csv data, I'm all ears.

```
//// Papa Parser 

Papa.parse("all_outages.csv", {
        download: false,
        delimiter: ",", 
        newline: "",    // auto-detect
        quoteChar: '"',
        escapeChar: '"',
        header: false,
        transformHeader: undefined,
        dynamicTyping: false,
        preview: 0,
        encoding: "",
        worker: false,
        comments: false,
        step: undefined,
        error: undefined,
        skipEmptyLines: false,
        chunk: undefined,
        fastMode: undefined,
        beforeFirstChunk: undefined,
        withCredentials: undefined,
        transform: undefined,
        complete: function (results) {
            console.log("Finished:", results.data);
        }
    });
```

With Papa.parse Im getting

```
Finished: 
[Array(1)]
0: Array(1)
0: "all_outages.csv"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I can get the same data that is in the csv from a sql db, and honestly, if I can save time and headaches, I am happy to do that. I just don't know how to get the sql table to an array that can be called in leaflet.

Comment: You're telling papa.parse to parse the **string** `"all_outages.csv"`. In order to parse a file, read the contents of the file or pass a `File` instance. And [RTFM](https://www.papaparse.com/docs#strings).

Comment: Thanx I will try that